# GLFW not rendering after call to SetParent()

Tags: user-interface, winapi, glfw

I'm trying to embed a **[glfw](https://www.glfw.org/)** window in another window using [**`glfwGetWin32Window()`**](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__native.html#gafe5079aa79038b0079fc09d5f0a8e667) and `SetParent()`.

The window embeds just fine, but it isn't rendering anything. I tried creating the window **without** embedding it and it works fine without the call to `SetParent()`.

I tried setting the **glfw** window's style to `WS_CHILD` and manually making it current like this:

```
HWND hWnd = glfwGetWin32Window(window);
SetParent(glfwGetWin32Window(hWnd, parentWindow);

DWORD style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~(WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION);
style |= WS_CHILD;
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);

HGLRC hglrc = glfwGetWGLContext(((my_plugin_t*)plugin->plugin_data)->window);
auto hdc = wglGetCurrentDC();
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc);
```

but neither seemed to work.

This is what I'm getting, the white area should be black:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I thought Raymond Chen had an Old New Thing blog post about this, but I can't find it right now, so perhaps is a false memory.  Here are ideas to explore:

- Try adding WS_CHILD to the window style *before* attempting to set the parent.
- Ensure the parent and child windows belong to the same thread.  Technically, I think you can have them in different threads, but there are many pitfalls to avoid.  I'd suggest getting it working in the same thread first.
- Could the glfw window have cached some information that's no longer valid once you convert the window from top-level to child?
- When you convert the window to a child (or to a top level window) you should probably set its size and position with SetWindowPosition function and include the SWP_FRAMECHANGED flag.